# Geforce 940MX not working after proprietary driver install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, laptop, intel-graphics

I have a laptop with integrated Intel GPU and GeForce 940MX.
With nouveau driver glxgears is working fine, but with proprietary nvidia drivers isn't:

```
$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

**NVIDIA X Server Settings** doesn't have any settings:
[NVIDIA X Server Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tORRY.png)

I've tried to install **nvidia-375** and **nvidia-381** via Driver Manager and manually via apt-get. Drivers are installed without errors, but they don't work.

Nvidia Prime has two equal options to switch to:

```
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
Info: the current GL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-381-prime', 'nvidia-381-prime']
Info: the current EGL alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-381-prime', 'nvidia-381-prime']
```

Here's the screenshot from Driver Manager:
[Driver Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/884Ms.png)

And lspci:

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 505c
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

**Update:**
Here's errors from Xorg.0.log:

```
[    13.919] (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for (null): -22
[    13.948] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

Thanks for any help.